# Came towards me running vs Came running towards me

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He came running towards me.
>
> He came towards me running.

Do you find both of the sentences natural?
Can we use both the sentences interchangeably?

Answer (score 1):

The first is far more natural to my ear.

The second expresses essentially the same meaning, but emphasises his mode of locomotion rather than his destination - it emphasises that he was *running*,  as opposed to, say, skateboarding or cartwheeling.  Since running is by far the more obvious verb in such a scenario, it sounds rather odd to emphasise it this way.  The only situation I can easily imagine using your second sentence is in poetry or literature.

Note that it is however natural to use a non-locomotion verb in that position, for example "He came towards me shouting".  This is because the locomotion verb is implied, "He came [running/walking] towards me [while] shouting".